# Font size effect javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to text effect like text increase size and decrease size loop with no limit using JavaScript

JavaScript:

```
 function fontSizer() {
  if (!document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize) {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "15px";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize == "15px") {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "10px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "15px"
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <p onload="fontSizer" id="font">Test</p>
```

Comment: The `load` event is not supported for `p` elements. And even if it would you would need to write: `onload="fontSizer()"`. So when do you want to change the font size?

Comment: just remove the onload from "p" and add call the fontSizer(); function from document.ready javascript method

Comment: using div tag it sill not working <div onload="fontSizer()" id="font">Test</div>

Comment: Supported HTML tags by onload : `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>`

Comment: Not exactly related, but variables are handy way to store data, for example `var element = document.getElementById("font");` and everywhere instead of endless requering the DOM, use `element`.

Comment: @Teemu: easier: this...

Comment: @Jonasw Is `this` is referring to the element when dealing with inline listeners? Maybe browser-dependent, but in FF [it seems to refer](https://jsfiddle.net/0yL2xb6t/) `window`.

Comment: @Teemu ive meant passing this : onclick="func(this)"

Comment: @Jonasw Then it will work. Though `onload` can't be set on `p`, hence not useful on this case, since the event has to be attached to a different element/object than which needs to be manipulated.

Comment: @teemu: jep youre right. Ive lost context

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this? Create some CSS classes, then use `element.classList.toggle('whateverYouCallTheClassesYouNeed')` on them. It's 2016, don't hack your way into the style object, we have nice APIs to do this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can raise the event on the body onload event.

```
<body onload="init()">
   <p id="font">Test</p>
</body>
```

This will call your function if you put it but one good way it to pass to an intermediate function where you call all this kinf of function (if you have several) :

```
function init() {
  fontSizer();
  //other method to call during the body loading
}
```

And if you want i can purpose you the following optimization for your code :

```
 function fontSizer() {
  var element = document.getElementById("font");

  if (element.style.fontSize == "15px") {
    elemeny.style.fontSize = "10px";
    return; 
  } 
  element.style.fontSize = "15px"
}
```

You can also use css animation by using something like :

```
#font {
    font-size: 15px;

   -webkit-animation: theanim 4s;
   -moz-animation: theanim 4s;
     -o-animation: theanim 4s;
        animation: theanim 4s;
}

@keyframes theanim {
    from { font-size:10px; }
    to   { font-size:15px; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Ansr But i am still have a problem i want too loop this

Comment: you want to call several time the function ? if yes have you try CSS animation ?

Comment: fix the css animation in my reply to reply to your need

Comment: so nice Sir i want to loop this how can i do this

Comment: the last parameter of animation directive are the repeat number of the animation. if you want infinite loop you can use the keyword infinite like the following animation: fadeIn 0.2s infinite;

Answer (score 0):

The text effect can be achieved by using onload event with `<body onload="fontSizer()>` tag.

```js
 function fontSizer() {
  if (!document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize) {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "15px";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize == "15px") {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "30px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = "15px"
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="fontSizer()"> 
<p  id="font">Test</p>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without javascript function, only with css animation :

```
#font {
    font-size: 15px;

   -webkit-animation: theanim 4s;
   -moz-animation: theanim 4s;
     -o-animation: theanim 4s;
        animation: theanim 4s;
}

@keyframes theanim {
    from { font-size:10px; }
    to   { font-size:15px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well JavaScript not work Good Its work fine with animation css

CSS:

```
<style>
@keyframes fadeIn { 
from { font-size: 20px; color:red;} 
 }

 .animate-flicker {
   animation: fadeIn 0.2s infinite alternate;
 }
 </style>
```

HTML

```
<span class="animate-flicker">Text</span>
```